# Get response from web browser for windows phone 'mango'

Tags: windows-phone-7, browser

I m my application I want to use Webbrowser which will be using Wifi,after the Webbrower opens the the link (task.URL) ,I want to check what is the response like whether the linked got opened or it failed.How do I do that means get the response ?

```
WebBrowserTask task = new WebBrowserTask();
task.URL = "https://www.goggle.com/";
task.Show();
```

kindly help

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, to catch this use NavigationFailed event as follow:

```
void WebPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.webHome.Navigate(new Uri(www,UriKind.Absolute));
    this.webHome.NavigationFailed += webHome_NavigationFailed;

}

void webHome_NavigationFailed(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
{
    this.webHome.NavigateToString("No web page available.");
}
```